# Python concurrent.futures: ProcessPoolExecutor giving BrokenProcessPool error

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

```
import random, matplotlib.pyplot as plt, time, math, multiprocessing, concurrent.futures
import numpy as np

def flatten(xss):
return [x for xs in xss for x in xs]


ram0=1024

def sticky_pos(iterations):
    do something
    return val

def main():
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        start_time = time.perf_counter()
        temp = list(executor.map(sticky_pos, [10 for i in range(int(iterations/10))]))  #int(iterations/10)
        finish_time = time.perf_counter()
    print(f"Program finished in {finish_time-start_time} seconds")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

pos=flatten(temp)
```

If I run this, I get an error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
BrokenProcessPool                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-dec2d19e0a0b> in <module>
     81 
     82 if __name__ == "__main__":
---> 83     main()
     84 
     85 pos=flatten(temp)

<ipython-input-1-dec2d19e0a0b> in main()
     76     with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
     77         start_time = time.perf_counter()
---> 78         temp = list(executor.map(sticky_pos, [10 for i in range(int(iterations/10))]))  #int(iterations/10)
     79         finish_time = time.perf_counter()
     80     print(f"Program finished in {finish_time-start_time} seconds")

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\process.py in _chain_from_iterable_of_lists(iterable)
    481     careful not to keep references to yielded objects.
    482     """
--> 483     for element in iterable:
    484         element.reverse()
    485         while element:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py in result_iterator()
    596                     # Careful not to keep a reference to the popped future
    597                     if timeout is None:
--> 598                         yield fs.pop().result()
    599                     else:
    600                         yield fs.pop().result(end_time - time.monotonic())

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py in result(self, timeout)
    433                 raise CancelledError()
    434             elif self._state == FINISHED:
--> 435                 return self.__get_result()
    436             else:
    437                 raise TimeoutError()

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py in __get_result(self)
    382     def __get_result(self):
    383         if self._exception:
--> 384             raise self._exception
    385         else:
    386             return self._result

BrokenProcessPool: A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending.
```

I've looked through previous posts with this error but in my code I have `__name__="__main__"`. What's really infuriating is that this code worked 8 months back. I just left it for few months and now it's giving this error. Any help would be greatly appreciated! I'm using windows 10 and I tried this in both jupyter notebook and spyder and getting same error. It works if I run it on ubuntu in terminal.

Comment: you have wrong indentations. And I think you should run `pos=flatten(temp)` inside `main()` because `temp` doesn't exist ouside `main()`

Comment: maybe you should use `logging` to write in file information what line of code was executed and what you have in variable - especially in part `do something` because this part can make problem too.